# Apache Kafka-Spark Streaming Exception

Tags: apache-spark, stream, kafka-consumer-api

I have created a simple word count application using an sbt script listed below:

name := **Spark Kafka Project**

version := **1.0**

scalaVersion := **2.10.5**

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.5.2"
```

I am using the below command to run it:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.5.2 --class "KafkaWordCount" --master local[4] target/scala-2.10/spark-kafka-project_2.10-1.0.jar localhost:2181 a my-first-topic 1
```

Running the program is returning the following exception :

```
17/02/07 12:26:10 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.136.8.39, 60153)
17/02/07 12:26:11 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@d3bf39{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:61)
    at KafkaWordCount$.main(KafkaWordCount.scala:20)
    at KafkaWordCount.main(KafkaWordCount.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.Spar`enter code here`kSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Please help me to figure out, what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try

1. launching with UBER jar including all dependencies
2. Placing all dependencies in HDFS and providing them with
   `--jar`parameter
3. Placing dependencies to exact same dir in every node and providing
   them with`--jar` parameter

Comment: Hi FaigB, Thanks for your response. Is there way I can create a fat jar file(by using sbt assembly plugin)? I have tried with  it  but facing issues like:[info] Set current project to Spark Kafka Project (in build file:/home/kafka-spark-sbt/)
[error] Not a valid command: assembly
[error] Not a valid key: assembly
[error] assembly
[error]      Can you please help  here too?